# How can I use shebang to differentiate between python versions

Tags: shell, rhel, python

We have a number of different versions of python which we `module load`. These can be a vanilla python 2 or 3 install, or an *anaconda* version with a whole load of extra libraries.

At the moment, if I write a script which requires me to use a specific python install (which I find using `module load python/ana ; which python`), I have to `#!` to an explicit path. For example

```
#!/path/to/anaconda/1.7.0/64/bin/python
```

points to the current version of python which is loaded when I do `module load python/anaconda` at the moment.

This module is not managed by me however, so if someone updates the module to use `/path/to/anaconda/1.7.1/64/bin/python` then deletes 1.7.0, my script will stop working.

Is there a standard way for a script to specify both the interpreter to use and the module the interpreter should be loaded from? Something like

```
#!/blah/module_env python/anaconda python -c
```

Alternatively, are there any other options which don't need root access? Our enterprise linux machines are locked down so that we can't install our own software, or change `/use/bin/env` configuration, just `module load` software which has been made available.

Comment: Perhaps try `module spider python` to see what versions of python you have available? You can also type `which python` and use that path as the shebang line.

Comment: I found lots of [environment modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_Modules_(software)) questions here on [unix.se] @StephenKitt, and started to tag them, any reason why you don't want an [tag:environment-modules] tag?

Comment: @Mark I don’t have anything against a new tag, if it’s useful, but the way you started tagging the questions wasn’t scrutable to anyone but you: there was no tag description, and no link to the relevant software. Feel free to resurrect the tag, but please document it first.

Comment: That's precisely how I found the location of the module loaded `python` in the first place @BarocliniCplusplus. I've edited my question to make that clear. Also, we are using standard [environment modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/), not an alternative implementation such as [Lmod](http://lmod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as implied by your `module spider` reference.

Comment: Sorry @StephenKitt, I hadn't got around to that writing up tag details, and all of my suggested edits were rejected. I'll give it another go when I have the time to do it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that `module` software of yours, but it looks like you should be able to do something like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
'eval' '. "$MODULES_HOME/init/sh"; module load something || exit; exec python -- "$0" "$@"'

python script follows
```

That will be first interpreted by `sh` which will then call `module` and execute `python` on the same script and with the same arguments.

The first two lines will be ignored by `python`, the first one because it's a comment, the second because it's just the concatenation of two strings.

More generally:

```
#! /bin/sh -
'eval' 'single-line-of-shell-code-with-no-single-quote; exec python -- "$0" "$@"'
```

Is a generic way to have an executable `python` script where some preamble shell code is run beforehand. For multiline shell code, you can also use `python`'s `'''...'''` quotes:

```
#! /bin/sh -
':' '''python script with shell preamble'

arbitrary shell code here provided it doesn't contain
a sequence of 3 single quotes.

exec python -- "$0" "$@"
'''

print("Hello World")
```

So here:

```
#! /bin/sh -
':' '''python script with shell preamble'
"$MODULES_HOME/init/sh"
module load something || exit
exec python -- "$0" "$@"
'''

python script follows
```